# Extending Java Third Party APIs

Tags: java, inheritance, classloader, extending-classes

Its more likely a subjective question. I wanted to create a sub class of a third party API to customize the behavior, but the problem is one of the method in API class is having default access specifier, and I am not allowed to override as my sub class is not in same package.

However, if I want a solution, I can put my subclass in same package as of API class and extend the method which has default access specifier. Third party jar file is licensed under  a permissive X11 type license (which is similar to  MIT License)

I am looking for answer for below queries

> 1. Is that legal to create subclass outside third party jar( different jar file) but maintaining similar package conversion?
> 2. Any known issue with this approach (even though same package name, I kept in two jars)( i just tested with stand alone unit test)
> 3. How Class loaders of app servers behave in such scenario ( which jar file will be loaded first)

Apologies if my query(1) related to license is not applicable here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1): The X11 license basically says you can do anything with the software as long as you credit the authors and don't sue them for breach of warranty. There is nothing illegal about what you suggest.

While what you suggest should work, it's hackish. The problem is that the third-party library is using an overly strict access specification for part of its API. The best way would be to *submit a patch* to the open-source project.

Your patch should simply specifies the method in question as `protected` instead of package-private, which would allow it to be called by subclasses (as well as other classes in the library's package, since `protected` includes package-private access). That way, it would also help other users of the library extend the class.

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't answer your first question because I don't have enough knowledge on this :)
2. It depends on your classloader. In common case the class that it sees first will be loaded. The second will be omitted. I wouldn't rely on classloader resolution order here, 
   The only thing you can be sure in is that the resources will be read from classpath.
   So if your classpath is
   `c:\a;c:\b` 
   and you have 2 files with the same name and package the one that resides in 'a' will be loaded first.
3. Inside the application server the classloaders usually implemented by the vendor of the particular server.
   For example wars usually are loaded with custom classloaders, different classloaders for different wars.
   The same holds for ears.
   The classloaders usually comprise an hierarchy in application servers.

So even if it technically works it can cause a lot of headache in future.

If its an open source project, I think the best would be submitting your patch to the open source community, or even compiling your own version (if the licence permits so).

Hope this helps